# How to take moment about point of contact in a hemisphere?

Tags: moment

[image]

[image]

In question 3, i am able to solve first part but in second part i don't know how to take moments about point of contact or about center ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Moments about the contact point c are:

form the mass m you get:

$$\vec{\tau_m}=\vec{r}_{cm}\times \vec{f}_m$$

form the mass M you get:

$$\vec{\tau_M}=\vec{r}_{cM}\times \vec{f}_M$$

with:

$$\vec{f}_m=\begin{bmatrix}
   0\\
   -m\,g\\
   0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\vec{r}_{cm}=\vec{r}_{0m}-\vec{r}_{0c}=\begin{bmatrix}
   a\\
   0\\
   0\\
\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}
   a\,\sin(\alpha)\\
   -a\,\cos(\alpha)\\
   0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\vec{\tau}_m=-m\,g\begin{bmatrix}
   0\\
  0 \\
  a-a\,\sin(\alpha) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

with:

$$\vec{f}_M=\begin{bmatrix}
   0\\
   -M\,g\\
   0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\vec{r}_{Mc}=\vec{r}_{0M}-\vec{r}_{0c}=\begin{bmatrix}
   0\\
   -3/8 a\\
   0\\
\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}
   a\,\sin(\alpha)\\
   -a\,\cos(\alpha)\\
   0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\vec{\tau}_M=-M\,g\begin{bmatrix}
   0\\
  0 \\
  -a\,\sin(\alpha) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\sum_\tau=0=-m\,g\,(a-a\,\sin(\alpha))+M\,g\,a\,\sin(\alpha)=0$$

Comment: What does this notification mean r0c and r0m

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the figure

Comment: One more thing if I take moment about point other than P - other corner of hemisphere- then equation becomes 0=Mga+2amg which is not right !!

Comment: Can u point out the mistake in this equation ??

Comment: @HarshitGupta I use the general equation for torque which is 
$\vec{\tau}=\vec{r}\times\vec{f}$ so my calculation is straight forwards

Answer (score 0):

With the center of gravity on the vertical line of symmetry for the hemisphere, the torque, produced by gravity, about the point of contact is just mg a sin(α) .

Comment: How did u deduce that ??

Comment: Torque = force times the perpendicular component of the radius.